# Is it possible to create and conect a Firebird database with Flask?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, firebird

I have a project in Flask that I was using SQLite to create and manage, but it won't work for big and heavy databases, so then I was thinking in another db and found Firebird. Is it possible to connect Firebird with Flask using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-firebird/